# Beautifulsoup - Getting values from a script tag

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'd like to extract the file links from a script tag.

How can i do it in python 2.7?

The structure is:

```
<more script tags>
<script>
var settings=
    {
    primary: 'user-o',
    opt: window.userfiles,
    files:  [
                    {
                        //title: "PDF File",
                        image: 'http://url.com/num-001/cover.jpg',
                        sources:
                            [
                                {
                                    'label': '',
                                    'file': 'http://url.com/user/0054552/file-1.pdf',
                                    'type': 'user-o'
                                },
                                {
                                    'label': '',
                                    'file': 'http://url.com/user/0054552/file-2.pdf'
                                }

                            ],

                        other:
                            [
                                {
                                    file: 'http://url.com/user/0054552/other-file-0.pdf',
                                    kind: 'other-files'
                                }
                            ]
                    }

            ]
    };
</script>
<more script tags>
```

I need all file links:

- ...url.com//user/0054552/file-1.pdf
- ...url.com//user/0054552/file-2.pdf
- ...url.com//user/0054552/other-file-0.pdf

I hope your support.

Thanks!

Comment: You already got this script tag by yourself? All you need is processing this block of text to obtain the urls?

Comment: Yes, by myself.

I need just the file links.

Comment: always pdfs files?

Comment: Yes, just pdf files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already got to this script, you just need to transform it in text and proccess it.

**This code will:**

1. `split` this script text block at each `\n`
2. `for` each string, search for substring `.pdf`
3. `if` string contains substring `.pdf`, `split` it at `': '`and `replace` `'` and `,`
4. `append` url part to a `list` called `files`
5. done

**Code:**

```
s = '''<more script tags>
<script>
var settings=
    {
    primary: 'user-o',
    opt: window.userfiles,
    files:  [
                    {
                        //title: "PDF File",
                        image: 'http://url.com/num-001/cover.jpg',
                        sources:
                            [
                                {
                                    'label': '',
                                    'file': 'http://url.com/user/0054552/file-1.pdf',
                                    'type': 'user-o'
                                },
                                {
                                    'label': '',
                                    'file': 'http://url.com/user/0054552/file-2.pdf'
                                }

                            ],

                        other:
                            [
                                {
                                    file: 'http://url.com/user/0054552/other-file-0.pdf',
                                    kind: 'other-files'
                                }
                            ]
                    }

            ]
    };
</script>
<more script tags>'''

files = []
data = s.split('\n')
for d in data:
    if '.pdf' in d:
        url = d.split(": ")[1].replace("'", "").replace(",", "")
        print(url)
        files.append(url)
```

**Output:**

```
'http://url.com/user/0054552/file-1.pdf'
'http://url.com/user/0054552/file-2.pdf'
'http://url.com/user/0054552/other-file-0.pdf'
```